# Keyup doesn't work for some dynamically created content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use keyup to validate input boxes like this:

```
$(document).on('keyup', ".answerBox", function () {
    var formID = this.id;
    answerCheck(formID);
    return false;
})
```

That works fine for dynamically created content. But I'm storing the progress with a cookie, and when the page is reloaded, the keyup-function stops working.

The problem is visible here:

http://ecation.org/lessons.html

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Answer the first question with "0". More content is added.
2. Reload the page. Answer the second question with "solid". More content should be added, but it's no longer working.

Comment: Where is the `keyup` handler in your code? I can only see the `answerCheck()` function.

Comment: on link it's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked at your code, you store clearedLevels as string but later you check it like:

```
clearedLevels === 1
```

Parse the value as integer when you read it from cookie, or check it with ==, so it will not check the data type.(keyup handler is still working)

Comment: Oh my, thank you! What a simple mistake :S It seems to work now!